# Bug or Temp Issue : Wrong Title in Questions Section

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I have just clicked on a Below Question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html
and I got this link opened [Is it possible for an iframe to redirect the parent page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171687/is-it-possible-for-an-iframe-to-redirect-the-parent-page)

Image 1: (Clicked This Link)
[image]

Image 2: (This Page Opened)
[image]

**Both the Images have Different Title for the same question.**

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it got edited 2 minutes after it was posted and the title changed... So yeah, that would be normal.

- If you had the page open for a long time, then obviously information can become outdated.
- If you used the live refresh button to load new questions, the questions appear in the list **as they were originally** when the question was posted. They will have a zero score, no views, original tags and title, etc. The information is not updated *when you click the button*. It is all the information as it was *when the live refresh notification went out*.

Comment: Ya Ctrl + F5 cleared that title and show same title now.